# Force rerender of some components when a button is click - React

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, express

From my  server file I have function that will pull up a set of data's based
on the id.

```
app.get('/musicbyid', function(req, res){
    var query = req.query.term.toLowerCase();
    music.find({ _id: query }, function(err, allMusic){
      if(err){
      console.log(err);
      } else {
      res.json(allMusic);
      }
  }) 
    console.log(req.query.term);
  });
```

and then on my react file I have a getMusicById function which will get the 
the click id and render the MusicListDetail Component w/c has specific info
about the item that was clicked:

```
class App extends Component{
 constructor(props){
   super(props);

   this.state = { 
     music: [],
     selectedMusic: null
  };

getMusicById(id) {
  axios.get('/musicbyid', {
      params: {
          id: id
      }
  })
  .then(music => this.setState({
      selectedMusic: music.data._id
  }))
  .then(() => console.log('this is is a state >>>>+++', this.state))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

This is a component where I listed all of the music that can be clicked vis button:

```
class MusicListItem extends Component{

  onClickImgMoreBtn(){
    console.log('hi there!');
   }

  render(){
  return (
 <a onClick={this.onClickImgMoreBtn} href={this.props.music._id} >
 <img className="card-img-top" src={this.props.music.poster_path} /></a>
  );
```

Again, when the button triggered via onClickImgMoreBtn was clicked
  it must then re-render the dom with the detail for that specific id with the ff component:

```
 const MusicDetail = ({music}) => {
  return (

      MUSIC ID:</strong>{music._id}</h4>
      MUSIC TITLE:</strong> {music.title}</h4>
  );
```

But I don't want to render all of the available components 
  so I was thinking on how I can do a conditional statement to 
  only render the header and the footer when the MusicDetail component
  was being re-rendered upon button clicked on the list.

1. How can I rerender the dom with the detail of the click id music detail
2. How can I do a conditional statement to render only a specific component
   while on the music detail component. Let's say I only want to render `<Header />`
   and `<Footer />`

   Sorry I am a beginner and I am really thinking hard on how I can pull all of these
   stuffs together.

Answer (score 0):

From [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)

> React DOM compares the element and its children to the previous one, and only applies the DOM updates necessary to bring the DOM to the desired state.

So if you have separated components like `<Header/>` and click on button will pass some new props to this component, that will not case entire DOM re-rendering. Only this exact component will be changed